# Add a png file to an xcode/swiftui project to simulate a downloaded file

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I want to simulate downloading an image file (png) and storing it in SwiftUI. How do I simply copy a file from finder into my xcode project so I can reference it for a test/demo? I want to get the raw bytes from it.

I've looked and it seems like you can copy things files into assets, but I'm not sure that will represent what I eventually want to do, which is download them and store them.

Is there any way to drag an image file into an xcode project?

Comment: just drag & drop it somewhere in your Xcode's Project Navigator on the left side. Make sure to click `Copy items if needed` and press `Finish`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SwiftUI

Comment: You can access the “raw bytes” of an image by loading it as a UIImage. It’s not very clear which part of image downloading you want to simulate, but in general if you want to handle images as Data you should look at the UIImage class.

Comment: @loremipsum, sorry. Should I put it in xcode?

Comment: Sure, but why not just drag the image? It will work. You may be meaning to ask a different question.

Comment: How do I reference it?

Comment: @loremipsum, I dragged it into swift and it's there. How do I access it using filemanager when running the code?

Comment: Just Google how to get a url for a project file in Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @stackish commented I clicked and dragged the png file into the project. There was a dialog message and I accepted the default settings.

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myimage", ofType: "png") else {
    print("Could not open file")
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A pretty comfortable way is the Asset Catalog

1. Select the Asset Catalog in the Project Navigator.
2. Click on the + button at the bottom of the asset list and choose Image Set.
3. Use a meaningful name for the asset for example `Placeholder`
4. Drag the image from the Finder into the 1x, 2x, or 3x square according to the resolution.
5. In the code use

   ```
   Image("Placeholder")
   ```

---

But why not still simpler with SF Symbols

```
Image(systemName: "photo")
    .font(.largeTitle)
```